# Maintaining list of testcases in an agile environment

Tags: tools, testcase

I am working on an agile team building a web-based product.

We do have [jUnit](http://junit.org/) tests and API automation as well. However since we iterate fast, more and more test-cases are being added or updated everyday.

My problem is that there is no central list of test-cases. 
Is there any tool which I can use to maintain list of tests and individual test details?

Comment: Why do you need a central list of tests? The tests are included with the code, not? And thus always up-to-date. Just make sure they do not break, run them daily on a continuous integration server. :)

Comment: I want to disable some tests based on the functionality in some builds. So I can get the list of tests and generate some list based on that , I can run only those tests. Not everything everytime.

Answer (score 2):

**Test documentation**:

It should be possible to generate code documentation with something like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) or [an alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/doxygen/). (Assuming all the automated test-cases are started with a (unit) test-runner which uses a sort of class system in code.) Run the doc-generator only on the directories containing the tests. This should result in a list of all methods in the classes. Each method is a test, this could be the list you are looking for. Often these tools generate a method list and details click-through in the form of HTML pages.

**Grouping tests**:

Understanding you want to run the test-suite partial. I think its better to group your test-cases and let the runner only start the groups you want to run.

Here are some links that describe grouping for popular test-runners:

- Visual Studio Tests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx
- jUnit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817135/grouping-junit-tests
- Cucumber: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags
- TestNG: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_group_test.htm

Start grouping the old tests and make sure everyone who creates a new tests to put it in one or more groups. Motivate them by telling them it will make local tests runs faster.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to avoid building custom application for tracking dependencies?

One way would be to have a wiki, one page per test. Wiki pages will have tags based on functionality. To run a test, you first run a search query on wiki, get pages matching criteria, convert page names to test names, and run them. And pages also can hold any other relevant info about tests. With version control.

This kind of flexibility is why FOS wiki (which we use) is going strong even if soon will be 20 years old.